# cronjob on ubuntu: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)

Tags: cron

my os is ubuntu: 16.0.4
PHP 7.2
Apache 2

i install cronjob on this os

error:

```
cron[30673]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
cron[30673]: (root) INSECURE MODE (mode 0600 expected) (crontabs/root)
cron[30673]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
```

Comment: How did you _"install cronjob on this os"_? What command did you use?

Comment: with this command: apt-get install cron

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like cron has the wrong permission and is owned by another user.

Fixing this is simple, run this command to change the ownership to cron.

> sudo chmod 600 /etc/crontab

Then this to restart cron

> sudo service cron restart

Comment: i run this command and check status, but see all error on first post , NOT FIX (cron[30673]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
cron[30673]: (root) INSECURE MODE (mode 0600 expected) (crontabs/root)
cron[30673]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)

Answer (score 1):

this error for directory

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

root is a file

run this command:

```
sudo chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently someone fiddled around with the permissions of user `root`'s crontab. For security reasons that file must have permissions `600` so that only root and the file's owner can read the file.

Go to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` and issue:

```
root@myhost:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# ls -l
total 4
-rw------- 1 pduck crontab 2551 Aug 22 11:53 pduck
-rw------- 1 root  crontab 1476 May 16 17:11 root
```

The output must be similar to the one shown above. If not, fix the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*
```